# Download latest artifacts from app center / Hockey app using API (token)

Tags: hockeyapp, visual-studio-app-center-test

Recently the hockey moved to app center and i want to download the latest version of android and iOS version on the fly using the API.

What I tried ?

checked the official swagger [api-specs](https://openapi.appcenter.ms)

```
1. @GET("/v0.1/apps/{owner_name}/{app_name}/recent_releases")
2. @GET("/v0.1/apps/{owner_name}/{app_name}/builds/{build_id}/downloads/{download_type}")
```

but the download url provided by the second url has a different host and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

The api's has been changed, and the new api we can use is

```kotlin
@GET("/v0.1/public/sdk/apps/{app_secret}/releases/latest")
    fun latestRelease(@Header("X-API-Token") apiToken: String, @Path("app_secret") secret: String): Call<JsonObject>
```

[offical swagger api](https://openapi.appcenter.ms/#/distribute/releases_getLatestPublicReleas)

- `app_secret` you can list your app secret using app list, use [this command line.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/api-docs/#from-app-center-cli)
- `apiToken` you can generate a token following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/api-docs/#acquiring-an-app-center-api-token)

Answer (score 3):

This API:

```
@GET("/v0.1/apps/{owner_name}/{app_name}/builds/{build_id}/downloads/{download_type}")
```

is to download builds if you use the Build service from App Center. If you only use Distribute service, try one of these APIs to get the release details, which includes the download url:

https://openapi.appcenter.ms/#/distribute/releases_getLatestByUser
https://openapi.appcenter.ms/#/distribute/releases_getLatestByDistributionGroup

Answer (score 2):

The API's changed, and /v0.1/public/sdk/apps/{app_secret}/releases/latest is no longer supported.
you can use instead

```
https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/sdk/apps/{app_secret}/releases/latest
```

Another better option then you can easily get any version is to use

```
https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/{owner_name}/{app_name}/releases/{release_id}
```

Get a release with id release_id or 'latest' to get the latest release that was distributed to the current user (from all the distribution groups).

[Swagger](https://openapi.appcenter.ms)